# UWP C# - Problems with Grid in a Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am writing a little app in C# for windows 10, and I have a listview as below, which is already in a grid.

However the grid I am adding to the listview doesn't expand out to fill the space, it is just grows as wide as the length of the data contained in the field bound to it. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to use fixed fields, I'd prefer to use a relative proportion of the page width.

Help!

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Margin="5" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="FolderMate" Style="{StaticResource SampleHeaderTextStyle}"/>

        <Button x:Name="GetFilesAndFoldersButton" 
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Content="Get files and folders" 
                Click="GetFilesAndFoldersButton_Click" 
                Margin="0,10,0,10"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="FileInfo"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"                      
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Margin="10" 
                Foreground="Green"/>
        <Button x:Name="ResetButton"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="5"
                Content="reset"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Click="ResetButton_Click" 
                Margin="0,10,10,0"/>

        <!--<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                      BorderBrush="Black"
                      BorderThickness="2"
                      Background="Chartreuse" 
                      Margin="0,5,0,5">-->
            <ListView x:Name="ThisList" 
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                      Background="LightBlue"
                      Margin="5"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"  
                      ItemClick="ThisList_ItemClick">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Border Background="Aquamarine" Grid.Column="0">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15 0"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" Margin="10" />
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="Cyan" Grid.Column="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FTime}" Margin="10"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="Tomato" Grid.Column="3">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
    </Grid>
```

Comment: ListView already provides scrolling capabilities unless I'm mistaken, do you really need a scroll view ?

Comment: Ok - didn't realise that, so have removed the scrollviewer code, but still the grid doesn't spread out into the width of columns defined in the column definitions.

Comment: I'm usually using Grid as a parent container - inside of it I place a Listview (and listview can have a grid for its rows :) )

Comment: That's what I have and the grid for the rows isn't working properly.

Comment: From the code posted I can see ListView being the parent container not Grid ..

Comment: Ok, I've edited my question and posted the containing grid as well - I do appreciate your assistance!

Comment: For ListView item container style set horizontalcontentalignment to stretch.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` inside `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` for `ListViewItem` to `Stretch`.

Your Full XAML For `ListView` will be like below.

```
<ListView x:Name="ThisList" 
              Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
              Background="LightBlue"
              Margin="5"
              ItemsSource="{Binding data}"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"  
              ItemClick="ThisList_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Background="Aquamarine" Grid.Column="0">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15 0"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" Margin="10" />
                </Border>
                <Border Background="Cyan" Grid.Column="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FTime}" Margin="10"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Background="Tomato" Grid.Column="3">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

See in the end, How I added `ItemContainerStyle` Targeting Only `ListViewItem`.

Final Output will be

[image]

Good Luck.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Might be it will helpful for you. I had used like that-

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ListView x:Name="UserMessageList">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local1:MessageModel">
                                            <StackPanel>

                                                //Add your conrole

                                            </StackPanel>

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that helps? Another reply says I don't need the scrollviewer and indeed I don't. It's the grid that isn't displaying correctly and there is no reference to it in your sample code.

Comment: Do you have a proportional width grid working in there?

Comment: Yes, Outer grid width and height fixed:                                                 <Grid  Width="800" Height="500" BorderBrush="#808080" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" >