# UWP ItemsStackPanel stretch HorizontalAlignment inside a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I have a ListView which always keeps its last entry in focus:

```
<ListView x:Name="invertedListView_lstv" Grid.Row="0" IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0, 10, 0, 0" SelectionChanged="invertedListView_lstv_SelectionChanged" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

If I add elements to this list they all show up on the left side. If I set the HorizontalAlignment to Right for the dark green ones, they also show up on the left side.

```
if (Chat.userAccountId.Equals(msg.fromUser))
{
    invertedListView_lstv.Items.Insert(0, new SpeechBubbleDownControl() { Text = msg.message, Date = msg.date.ToLocalTime(), HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right});
}
else
{
    invertedListView_lstv.Items.Insert(0, new SpeechBubbleTopControl() { Text = msg.message, Date = msg.date.ToLocalTime() });
}
```

[image: Example]

Is there a way to fix this, without sacrificing the KeepLastItemInView of the ItemsStackPanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` in `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`. Like below.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396727/uwp-c-sharp-problems-with-grid-in-a-listview/43397533#43397533) answer for more info